# MPMoviePlayerController switching from live to VOD stalling issue

Tags: video, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, switching

I'm trying to create a basic app on the iPad SDK 3.2, that displays one movie player that switches between different video sources.  Switching between VOD using the code below does not have any issues.  However if I switch to a live stream and then back to a VOD the video player constantly stalls.

I've also tried releasing then re-creating the player before switching video, but this has the same issue.  Any help will be very much appreciated.

```
 (void)moviePlayerWithUrl:(NSURL*)url {

 if( self.moviePlayer ) {
  [self.moviePlayer setContentURL:url];
 }
 else {
  self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
  self.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
  [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
  self.moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(200, 100, 400, 300);
  self.moviePlayer.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
  self.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just an effect of using the simulator, once the code is running on an actual device this issue will not be seen.